# Batch File to Loop Through Remote Git Branches and Copy a Similar CSV File in Each Branch to a Local Directory

Tags: windows, git, batch-file, command-line

I'm very new to batch scripting.

To elaborate on my question, there's a specific file that's found in many different remote git branches, each csv file being different in its contents across the branches, but similar in naming convention. I am trying to write a batch file that loops through each remote git branch and copies this file to a local directory.

Thankfully, each remote branch follows the same naming convention: a 3-digit-ID, an underscore, and the word update (e.g. `018_update`). The source directory has the following naming format: a 3-digit-ID, a space, and a text-based name with spaces (ex: `\018 To Shreds - You Say`).

I've gotten as far as being able to get the branch names into a list, and then looping through each one, but now I'm stuck. One issue I'm wondering how to navigate is whether I'll be able to use a wildcard on the `%%a` to extract the 3-digit-ID from the remote branch name and use it to locate the directory (and filename) that also both contain the 3-digits in there.

Here's what I've written so far:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a  IN (
 'git branch -r --list "*???_update*" '
 ) DO (
    git checkout %%a
)
)
```

Assuming this is the right direction to go, I feel that all that's left would be to find a way to get the 3-digit-ID from the remote branch name (i.e. `%%a`) and use it to make a wildcard and locate the file I want to copy/paste out of there.

Thank you in advance for anyone able to help me tackle this!

Comment: See `help set`.  Also `help call` and `help setlocal`. I would use a simple `...do @call ...` rather than the a multiline code block in parens `...do (...multi-line code block...).

Comment: Do you use remote names other than `origin`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This demonstrates how to parse strings of the form `<origin>/<###_name*>` into two variables `%%a` and `%%b`, then set `_id` equal to the three digit prefix of the branch name. If your branch names look more like `<origin>/*###_name*`, then we'll have a little more work to do, and I can help you with that later on.

```
@setlocal EnableExtensions

@for /F "tokens=1,* delims=/" %%a  in ('git branch -r --list *???_upate*') do @call :DoIt "%%a" "%%b"
@exit /b

:DoIt
@REM Ignoring %1, corresponding to %%a, because it's the name of the remote. 
@set "_b=%~2"
@set "_id=%_b:~0,3%"
@echo _id
@REM Use _id to find your directory and file name here.
@exit /b 0
```